# Javascript and classname element

Tags: javascript, html

really new to so please forgive me if this is a silly question...

I'm trying to use the     `var images = document.getElementsByClassName("imagesArea");`

and it keeps coming up as undefined,

this is my class in HTML `<div class="imagesArea">`

but I have no idea why it isnt finding it? My javascript doc is linked etc

Thanks

edit: it works fine adding an ID to the html div, but I'm not sure why it isnt working with clasname?

```
<div class="imagesArea">

<div class="images">
    <figure>
        <a href="photos/image1.jpg"><img src="photos/image1.jpg" alt=”Photo” width=150 height=150></a>
    <figcaption>Watch #1</figcaption>
    </figure>

    </div>

<div class="images">
    <figure>
        <a href="photos/image2.jpg"><img src="photos/image2.jpg" alt=”Photo” width=150 height=150></a>
    <figcaption>Watch #2</figcaption>
    </figure>

</div>
</div>
```

Comment: it shouldn't come undefined atleast it will be giving `[]`.

Comment: please show us your code

Comment: that is my code? @Dasarp. I can get it working by adding an ID to the div class but that still doesnt explain why.

Comment: Dasarp means your html!

Comment: @Mritunjay — It returns a NodeList, not an Array.

Comment: var image1 = document.getElementsByClassName("imagesArea")[0]

Comment: @Quentin ya I know that but in console it prints both the same.

Comment: Provide a *complete* reduced test case to show us your problem. Include the HTML and the JS and enough code to show us how (and where in the HTML) you are including the JS.

Comment: If there aren't any elements with that class name you'll get an empty collection, e.g., `[]`. I suspect something else is happening; is there anything in your JavaScript console?

Comment: yep, im doing alerts and console.log's and it all works fine. it even just worked fine assigning an ID to the div class.

Comment: it worked by adding an ID, but still querying with `getElementsByClassName`? I can guarantee you that another part of the code is giving you the illusion that `getElementsByClassName` is returning undefined. It's probably never running and you're checking the return value asynchronously

Comment: works fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/John_C/m8yyoopa/1/

Comment: You've added more HTML, but you haven't added all the information that my previous comment asked for. You should also show us how you are determining that the value is undefined.

Comment: I don't think its another part of the code. as soon as I press a button it gets returned.

Comment: You need to describe the problem clearer.  "it keeps coming up as undefined" -> what is "it" ? "im doing alerts and console.log's and it all works fine" -> What does console.log() show?

Comment: can you provide full code.with javascript?

Comment: Thanks for the assistance. it has been solved. the issue was I was not adding at what index I wanted. i.e. document.getElementsByClassName("imagesarea")[0];

Comment: What Browser is in use? Maybe some mobile Browser don't have implement document.getElementsByClassName.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work fine

```
var image1 = document.getElementsByClassName("imagesArea")[0];
```

By Id you get an element so if you do it works but by class name you have to iterate over them because it gets elements in an array like object.

Ex-

```
var image1 = document.getElementsByClassName("imagesArea");
for (var i=0;i<image1.length;i++){
image1[i].style.color='red';
}
```

Comment: Since the OP says that `document.getElementsByClassName("imagesArea")` returns `undefined`, adding `[0]` to it should throw an error.

Comment: @Quentin But we know it will never return undefined, don't we?

Comment: okay awesome that makes sense, so basically since returning a classname can return multiple elements they get stored as an array? Therefore you need to select at what index you want to get?

Answer (score 0):

This should work as you have it. Confirm using something like JS Fiddle. Please check if you're running the script properly.

http://jsfiddle.net/remix1201/qonatxnf/

Please see that fiddle.

JS:

```
var images = document.getElementsByClassName("imagesArea");
alert(images);
```

Comment: If you can't reproduce the problem, then (when you have enough reputation) comment such and vote to close the question as reproducible.  This doesn't solve the problem. The OP says they have already tested in JSFiddle and it works there.

Comment: Why the downvotes? This proves that the example as written does work, doesn't it?

Comment: I don't have enough rep to comment on an actual post yet. :\

Comment: @JuanMendes — Proving that the OP doesn't have a problem doesn't solve their problem.

Answer (score -1):

Did you define this class name in your html code.

for image tag

```
<img src="" class="imagesArea" />
```

Comment: The code in the question shows that they did (although for div elements)